# How to use LEFT JOIN in DOCTRINE

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

I have used following code for simple join in Doctriner in Codeigniter:

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT u.name,u.subject,pds.subject_name FROM PdContact u,PdSubject pds WHERE pds.id=u.sub_id');
```

But how to do left join? When I tried to to left join it shows error.

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
    $sql = "SELECT u.name,u.subject,pds.subject_name FROM PdContact u LEFT JOIN PdSubject pds  ON pds.id=u.sub_id;";
    $connection = $this->em->getConnection();
    $cleanreq = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $cleanreq->execute();
    $result = $cleanreq->fetchAll();
    return $result;
```

For more infos on Joining you can check this doc : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: @ManojBorah Welcome :) you can set it as accepted answer.